# Lock Timeout when creating index in ArangoDB

Tags: indexing, arangodb

I am able to connect to the coordinator of my ArangoDB cluster using the following:

```
sudo arangosh --server.endpoint tcp://10.32.0.15:1027
```

Everything works (CRUD, querying, etc.), except when I try to create an index I get a "Lock Timeout" error:

```
10.32.0.15:1027@_system> db.imdb_vertices.ensureIndex({ type: "skiplist", fields: ["name"] })
JavaScript exception in file '/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/arangosh.js' at 100,7: ArangoError 18: : lock timeout
!      throw error;
!      ^
stacktrace: ArangoError: : lock timeout
    at Object.exports.checkRequestResult (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/arangosh.js:98:21)
    at ArangoCollection.ensureIndex (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/arango-collection.js:738:12)
    at <shell command>:1:18

10.32.0.15:1027@_system>
```

I get the same error when I try to create the index over HTTP:

```
$ curl -X POST --data-binary @- --dump - http://10.32.0.15:1027/_api/index?collection=imdb_vertices << EOF
{
    "type" : "skiplist",
    "fields" : [
        "name",
        "genre"
    ]
}
EOF

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: ArangoDB
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 71

{"error":true,"code":400,"errorNum":18,"errorMessage":": lock timeout"}
```

From the docs, I see "Will be raised when there's a timeout waiting for a lock." is listed as the cause of the error. However, I am unable to find a solution. Any hints?

Thanks!